# Как расшифровать полученый код python

Tags: python

У меня есть код:

```
result = []
data = b'hello'
for b in data:
    result.append(list(map(int, f'{b:08b}')))
print(result)
```

Он выводит:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Вопрос: Как можно расшифровать полученный результат (т.е. сделать обратную функцию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
a = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

def decode(seq: list[list[int]]) -> bytes:
    return bytes(int(''.join(str(bit) for bit in bits), base = 2) for bits in seq)

print(decode(a))
# hello
```